# par(mfrow=c(1,2)) not displaying side-by-side plots

Tags: r, plot

When I try to display two plots in one graph, I only get an output from the last plot when using par(mfrow= c(1,2))

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

a <- plot(effect(fit.no_interaction, term="WEEK", confidence.level = 0.95, residuals=T),
     colors="blue", band.colors="red", band.transparency=0.3, rug=F, cex=5,
     residuals.color=adjustcolor("cornflowerblue", alpha.f=0.2),
     residuals.pch=16, smooth.residuals=F)

b <- plot(effect(fit.interaction, term="YEAR", confidence.level = 0.95, residuals=T),
     colors="blue", band.colors="red", band.transparency=0.3, rug=F, cex=5,
     residuals.color=adjustcolor("cornflowerblue", alpha.f=0.2),
     residuals.pch=16, smooth.residuals=F)

print(a, position = c(0, 0, 0.5, 1), more = TRUE)
print(b, position = c(0.5, 0, 1, 1))
```

This resulted in an output where only (b) was plotted instead of (a) and (b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a base R solution, but the [`cowplot`](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/plot_grid.html) package makes plotting graphs side-by-side very easy.

```
library(effects)
library(cowplot)
data(mtcars)
fit.no_interaction <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + qsec, data = mtcars)
fit.interaction <- lm(mpg ~ cyl*qsec, data = mtcars)

a <- plot(effect(fit.no_interaction, term="cyl", confidence.level = 0.95, residuals=T),
          colors="blue", band.colors="red", band.transparency=0.3, rug=F, cex=5,
          residuals.color=adjustcolor("cornflowerblue", alpha.f=0.2),
          residuals.pch=16, smooth.residuals=F)

b <-  plot(effect(fit.interaction, term="cyl", confidence.level = 0.95, residuals=T),
          colors="blue", band.colors="red", band.transparency=0.3, rug=F, cex=5,
          residuals.color=adjustcolor("cornflowerblue", alpha.f=0.2),
          residuals.pch=16, smooth.residuals=F)

plot_grid(a, b)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! I ran the code as instructed and it did the job perfectly!

Comment: If you think this answer adequately satisfies your original question, don't forget to check the green checkmark.